# R ggplotly show discrete variable tooltip as discontinuous number instead of category

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm trying to show a category tooltip for a discrete variable, however, the tooltip treats the discrete category as a continuous number.

Please see the following example. The tooltip for the sex variable is shown as sex 0.7, sex 1.0, etc instead of M or F. Any fix?

Thanks!

```
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
 df <- survival::pbc
gplot <- ggplot(df,aes(x=sex,group=trt,fill=trt))+geom_bar(position = "dodge")
ggplotly(gplot,tooltip=c('x','y','group'))
```

As Quinten pointed out that you should use 'fill' instead of 'group'. Ironically, if creating exact same graph in R shiny, utilizing ggplotly for subplots will cause the same issue even only 'fill' was used. I'm leaving a note here to help people who may come across this situation.

```
# This works outside R shiny app or only one graph
ggplotly(gplot,tooltip=c('x','y','fill'))

# If using for plotly subplots, this same issue will come back.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there is a type in `tootip->tooltip`. You should turn of the `group` aesthetic and make sure you use the `fill` aesthetics to show the right labels like this:

```r
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
df$trt = as.factor(df$trt)
gplot <- ggplot(df,aes(x=sex,fill=trt))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
ggplotly(gplot,tooltip=c('x','y','fill'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but if you put group back in, the tooltip still shows numerical instead of sex:f etc

Comment: Hi @ponyhd, Yes that's why you don't need the group aesthetic for tooltip.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I was using this for R shiny, one note that using ggplotly within plotly_build function will cause the same issue no matter if 'fill' or 'group' was used.